# $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected. Why is $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \begin{cases}0 & x\in U \\ 1 & y\in V \end{cases}$continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I quote:
"
In fact, $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is also connected: namely, if there were a representation $[a,b] =U \cup V$
with disjoint subsets $U$ and $V$ that are open in $[a,b]$, this is how the mapping would be:

$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \begin{cases}0 & x\in U \\ 1 & y\in V \end{cases}$"

Why is $f$ continuous?

The Definition below $(*)$ is my reference point:

I get that the inverse images $f^{-1}(\{0 \})=U$ and $f^{-1}(\{1 \})=V$ are open but $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are closed sets.

If $f$ is really continuous then this would indeed be a contradiction to the intermediate value theorem.

$(*)$One of the definitions of a continuous function $f$ in metric spaces is:

($f:M\to N$ is continuous)$\Leftrightarrow$ (For every open set $U\subset N$, $f^{-1}(U)\subset M$ is also open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each open $W \subset \mathbb R$ either contains

- none of $0,1$ in which case $f^{-1}(W) = \emptyset$
- exactly one of $0,1$ in which case $f^{-1}(W) = U$ or $f^{-1}(W) = V$
- both of $0,1$ in which case $f^{-1}(W) = [a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

> If $f$ is really continuous then this would indeed be a contradiction to the intermediate value theorem.

That's the point of the proof. As @KritikerderElche showed, $f$ is continuous. But if $U$ and $V$ are not empty, it does not satisfy the conclusion of the Intermediate Value Theorem. Therefore, $U$ or $V$ should be empty. This means that $[a,b]$ is connected, as one possible definition of connectedness is

> A topological space $X$ is connected if it cannot be written as the union of two **nonempty** disjoint open subsets.

Answer (score 1):

$U=f^{-1}((-\frac 12, \frac 12)), V=f^{-1}((\frac 12, \frac 32))$, so both $U$ and $V$ are preimages of open sets in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: This does not show that $f$ is continuous. There are more of open sets in $\mathbb R$ and you have to look at their preimages.

Comment: I don't think that was his point, he just gave me a hint that my focus is to much on the sets $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$. Thats why I gave it an upvote.